# How can I reference multiple XNA content projects from my game project?

Tags: xna, c#

I'm developing an engine in XNA and would like to have two different ContentManagers: one for the game (sprites, sounds, etc.) and one for the engine (shaders, dlls, etc.)

Right now, I have this:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
....
public class Engine
{
    public ContentManager GameContent;
    public ContentManager EngineContent;
    public IServiceContainer Services = null;

    public Engine(GraphicsDeviceManager Graphics, ContentManager Content)
    {
        Services = new ServiceContainer();
        Services.AddService(typeof(IGraphicsDeviceService), Graphics);
        Services.AddService(typeof(IGraphicsDeviceManager), Graphics);
        GameContent = Content;
        EngineContent = new ContentManager(Services, "EngineContent");
        ...
    }
}
```

The GameContent and EngineContent projects root directories are set to GameContent and EngineContent, respectively. I have a content reference to EngineContent in the Engine project and references to both GameContent and EngineContent in the Game project.

Why can I access my GameContent but not my EngineContent?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm trying to build an engine completely separate from my game. But I want to be able to implement certain graphical features straight from the engine so I need to be able to use my .fx files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Something about referencing the engine content from both the game and the engine was messing it up. Removing the EngineContent reference from the game cleared it up.